# Apache w/mod_rails segmentation fault

Tags: linux, apache2, redmine, mod-rails, centos5

I am running Redmine on Apache 2 with mod_rails (passenger) 2.0.3 and Enterprise Ruby 1.8.6. Every so often I get a segfault from Apache when I try to login. Anyone know how I can debug this issue? I see something like this in Apache's error.log:

[Mon Jan 19 17:09:48 2009] [notice] child pid 8714 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

The only way I can get the application to work after that is restart the whole system (restarting Apache only doesn't help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First steps are:

1. Find out where the core file is being left on your system (enable core dumps if necessary).
2. Run `file(1)` on the resulting core file. This will probably say "... generated by httpd", but it's as well to check.
3. Fire up `gdb` against the executable name from (2) and the core file from (1), and start digging. The command `where` (or `bt`) is a good place to start: this will give you a stack trace at the time the process dumped core.

It sounds like you don't have a mass of C coding experience, so good luck! Tracking down this kind of error can be a real dog. You can try posting the stack trace from (3) here, but don't hold your breath whilst waiting for an answer. At best, the failing function name might be a good string to feed to Google.

Comment: On most systems you will have to enable core dumps with this command: ulimit -c 9999999

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a segfault (11). Found the following [question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/351651/modrails-for-apache2-setup-failing-to-load) which offered an upgrade as a solution.

Was running an older version of Ubuntu and had the segfault problem. A `do-release-upgrade` brought my system to Ubuntu 11.10 and the problem magically went away.